# Equation for 3D graphing of ellipsoid with that has 2 open ends opposite each other

Tags: equation, wolframalpha

The equation (X^2)/25+(Y^2)/25+(Z^2)/2=1 yields a 3D ellipsoid figure on WolframAlpha. However I am trying to find out how to enter an equation that will give me a form with the ellipsoid open at 2 ends.  One way would be to restrict the domain of x such that x is between -3.5 and 3.5 .  But I can't figure out the notation for that in the WolframAlpha text box.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for Mathematica.  It happens to work in Wolfram Alpha also.  (It's not generally true that Mathematica code runs in WA.)

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2/25 + y^2/25 + z^2/2 == 1, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

[image]